# Spice code for a memristor-based gas sensor: node error

Tags: ltspice, pspice, hspice, gas-sensor, memristor

I have written Spice code for a memristor-based gas sensor but it is displaying a node error. The error and the code are attached as images:

[image: the error display image]

```
*VTEAM SPICE model modified for sensing
.SUBCKT MEM_sens TE BE XSV C

.params Ron=100 Roff=16000 alphaoff=3 alphaon=3 von=1.2 voff=0.7 koff=8e-13 kon=8e-13 xoff=3e-9 xon=0 xinit=3e-9 p=1 beta=9 A=2

*Function D(x,v) - State Variable motion
.func D(V1,V2) = IF (V2 >= voff, IF(V2 <= von,0,kon*pow((V2/von-1),alphaon)*f(V1,V2)),koff*pow((V2/voff-1),alphaoff)*f(V1,V2))

*Reff function for reducing gas
.func Reff(V3) = Ron*(1+A*pow(V3,beta))

*Reff function for oxidising gas
*.func Reff(V3) = Ron/(1+A*pow(V3,beta))

*Assignment of the initial state variable
.ic V(XSV) = xinit

*Capacitance to determine the state variable
Cx XSV 0 {1}

*stp function
.func stp(i)= IF (i >= 0, 1 , 0 )

* Biolek Window Function
.func f(V1,V2)=1-pow(((V1-xon)/(xoff-xon)-stp(V2)),(2*p))

*Current source to determine the state variable
Gx 0 XSV value = {D(V(XSV,0),V(TE,BE))}

*Conductance function
.func G(V1,V3) = pow((Reff(V3)+(Roff-Reff(V3))*(V1-xon)/(xoff-xon)),-1)

* Current source for memristor IV response
Gm TE BE value = {G(V(XSV,0),V(C,0))*V(TE,BE)}

*End of the model
.ENDS MEM_sens
```

Comment: nc_02 is probably its internal name for a node you refer to, but have not explcitly named. Try adding node labels to your schematic, and referring to those in your dependant source equations.

Comment: What happens if you draw some wires to the not-connected `C` and `XSV` pins, even if they don't connect to anything?

Comment: Why not post the contents of the subcircuit as a `text` (use ``` as pre- and post-delimiters). That way it's easy to copy-paste as test for yourself, instead of expecting people to type, or judge by inspection, only. For example, I can see that `Gx` relies on the `XSV` node for its formula (which is what @SteKulov hints at), but I won't go through the trouble of dissecting a picture, instead of a text file. Help us help you.

Comment: I have tried adding pin levels to xsv and c terminal but it has concluded in error: u1:gm: Unknown circuit node: 'c 'requested in behavioural source. But now it is clear which node is resulting in error @SteKulov . What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen replaced the image by the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Gm` definition:

```
Gm TE BE value = {G(V(XSV,0),V(C,0))*V(TE,BE)}
```

references `V(C,0)` which is the voltage between the internal node `C` and node zero.  But node `C` doesn't connect to anything, neither internally within the subcircuit nor through the external pin of the subcircuit instance on your schematic.  You're basically requesting a voltage at a nonexistent node and that's what the error message is highlighting.  You don't have this problem with `XSV` because your `Gx` definition establishes `XSV` as an actual node inside the subcircuit.  You need to do something similar with `C` or, alternatively, connect it externally to something with a DC path to node zero so it doesn't float (e.g. a `1g` resistor to GND).